# LXC 0.9.0 error

Tags: lxc

I am using lxc 0.9.0 and which we compiled and then created busybox container named 'yashu'
but started it ,it gives following error

```
yashu@yashu-pc:~$ sudo lxc-start -n yashu 
lxc-start: failed (98) to create the command service point /usr/local/var/lib/lxc/yashu/command
lxc-start: ##
lxc-start: # The container appears to be already running!
lxc-start: ##
lxc-start: failed to initialize the container
```

please help

Answer (score 1):

Try stopping the container with lxc-stop and then starting it again. Sometimes this will happen on the first start.